# Is it possible to use toString on an variable with type InetAddress

Tags: java

am writing a program in java on Linked List. I get an error when i use toString to return the IP address and PC of the code below.

```
package linked;

import java.net.InetAddress;

public class Work {
    private InetAddress IP;
    private String PC;

    public Work(InetAddress IP, String PC){
        this.IP=IP;
        this.PC=PC;
    } 
    public InetAddress getIP(){
        return IP;
    }
    public String getPC(){
        return PC;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return IP + ' ' + PC;
    }
}
```

It comes up with an error in the `@Override` that says

> bad operand types for binary operator '+'   first type:  InetAddress
>   second type: char

Comment: Try using `" "` instead of `' '`.

Comment: Also note that by convention, your fields should be `ip` and `pc`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return IP.toString() + " " + PC; 
}
```

`IP.toString()` will give you all the properties of IP object. If you just need host address, then use `IP.getHostAddress() + " " + PC;`

`'` is used for `char` datatype and `"` is used for `String` datatype in java.  `+` operator is overloaded to do numeric operations or concatenate `String`. So, it will concatenate the strings.

Comment: You can concatenate a `char` to a `String`. There's no need to replace `' '` by `" "`.

Comment: Oh yeah, then earlier it was because of IP was not string, but why complicate things by putting in a character when you can use empty String.

Comment: It's not an empty string (it contains a space) and it's not complicated. You can add a number to a `String` as well. In fact, you can add any primitive or object to a string.

Comment: I get it. Its not an empty String, space is there in this question. I know that we can add a number to a String and a common way to convert a number to string by concatenating it to an empty string. The same idea, I mentioned in answer that `+` operator is overloaded.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to call `IP.getHostAddress()` or `IP.ToString()` methods?

```
@Override
public String toString() {
return IP.getHostAddress() + " " + PC;
}
```

Please refer to the documentation at:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html